# integrating input fields using IME with "Scene" in samsung smart tv?

Tags: javascript, html, samsung-smart-tv, ime

Below mentioned code is able to show me keypad but the problem is after pressing any key it gives me `"body is not activated....."` because of

```
document.getElementById("userid").focus();
```

But If I remove `document.getElementById("userid").focus();` Keypad will not generate and Keys are started working

Sample Code for IME

```
SceneSignIn.prototype.handleShow = function (options) {
    alert("SceneSignIn.handleShow()");
    // this function will be called when the scene manager shows this scene
    this.ime_plainText = new IMEShell("userid");    
    this.ime_passwordText = new IMEShell("password");
    document.getElementById("userid").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

1. You have the default on new javascript application anchor element in index body. This:
   `<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anchor" onkeydown="main.keyDown(event);"></a>`
2. Your focus management in the application is not being interfered when you give the input element focus.